# Docusign integrated with Ariba CLM - Signature status takes hours to update

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, sap-ariba

Good day to all,

In the context of my project, we integrated Docusign to SAP Ariba CLM (contract Lifecycle management).
We are using the esignature task in our contract workspaces.
Once all parties have signed the contract in Docusign, **it takes hours** for the esignature task status to move from "signing" to "signed" in Ariba. It also takes hours for the contract signed PDF to be pushed from Docusign to the contract workspace in Ariba.

I have already worked with other esignature providers (for instance AdobeSign) and the update of the signature status took 5 minutes at most.

I think we need to change the esignature status refresh frequency but i'd like to know where this would be done. In Ariba ? or in the DocuSign Account ?

Many thanks for your insights and my apologies for my question phrased with simple words. I'm functional, not technical.

[screenshot of the Ariba-Docusign integration configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYYRW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Signature status and document could be transmitted by Docusign to Ariba either through API request or a Connect configuration. You would need to verify what has been implemented.

In the 1st case, it would mean to change the frequency when Ariba makes his API call against Docusign to check the envelope status. If you are in this situation, you should contact SAP support to operate this change.

In the 2nd case, you would need to verify if Connect configuration uses aggregate or SIM (Send Individual Messages) mode. When using aggregate mode, messages are not systematically sent to the 3rd party as soon as a Docusign event occurs, but an algorithm will wait to aggregate several messages together, and could explain the delay you observe
If you are in this situation, you should open a support case to Docusign if you need further help.

Comment: Good day Sylvain

Many thanks for your answer.
You said: "Signature status and document could be transmitted by Docusign to Ariba either through API request or a Connect configuration."

If we integrated docusign to Ariba using the log in credential of the docusign administration application, does this mean we fall into the category of a "Connect Configuration" ? I added a screenshot of the configuration we implemented.

Thank you !

Comment: This screen capture only shows there is at least a usage of Docusign API by SAP. But this is normal. You should check if there is a Connect configuration related to SAP under Docusign web UI in Settings>Connect
If there is nothing, then we will be sure Docusign API are used to sync signature status and document under SAP

Answer (score 0):

The default refresh interval for syncing the task status is [120 minutes](https://help.sap.com/docs/ARIBA_SOURCING/fa6038501b9b4b548e7a7628356e33ca/7d1610f071ea1014b08a9051a01751bd.html). You can create a support request with SAP Ariba to have this updated to be more frequent (the minimum is [30 minutes](https://help.sap.com/docs/ARIBA_SOURCING/fa6038501b9b4b548e7a7628356e33ca/7d12869c71ea10148671810608e828e9.html#loio7d00b24271ea1014a0fea908e2b3b9db)).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from default refresh rate there is a option in Ariba to manually trigger the sync process. Please search for this "Updating the Status of Signature Tasks" on Ariba connect